# Reset a variable on a specific time (also keep doing this after app restart)

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

So I want a variable to reset to 0 at a specific time of day. I got this part working.

But every time the app restarts, the alarm stops working.

I got a “TimePicker” that gets a time from the user and then this method is called.

```
public void setAlarmResetDose(long timeInMillis) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmResetTaken.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

That method above calls the class “AlarmResetTaken” which is a “BroadcastReciver” class that runs the code to reset the variable.

But like I said this only work as long as the app is running. When the app restarts, the alarm only starts working again when the user puts in a new time with the “TimePicker”.

**My attempt to solve the problem**

I used the code from the TimePicker and saved it in a variable:

```
timeDoseResetTotal = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

I also used sharedPreferences to save this time.

Then in the MainActivity onCreate i loaded the sharedPreferences value and ran the method “setAlarmResetDose(timeDoseResetTotal);” (with that value).

However this don’t seems to work.

Anyone got any ideas on how I could get this to work? :/

**Edit:**

I created this method and called it in MainActivity onCreate.

```
    public  void startAlarmBroadcastReceiver() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                timeDoseResetHour,
                timeDoseResetHour,
                0

        );
        setAlarmResetDose(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Where "timeDoseResetHour" and "timeDoseResetMin" are loaded with SharedPreferences fromearlier. It now works if the user opens the app before the time, but not after. So i guess if you re-open the app after the specific time it goes of  the next day instead. Any ideas? :)

Comment: Edit 2: That last code i added in MainActivity don't seem to work actually. it seems more like to reset my variable randomly now :°(

Comment: I would look at requirements around scheduling alarms in the future. Google is very strict regarding scheduled background work, and on newer api's will not allow you to set an alarm to fire at an exact time. I would investigate the class `JobService`, `JobScheduler`, and the whole `Job` api to see if this fits your needs.

Comment: Ok thanks Elli. Do you think i could use the Job api to do a reset on an variable on a specific time every day?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/background looks like AlarmManager is in fact the right class based off this documentation. I'll take a further look at your question later and see if I can parse what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) appears to be the method you need. The tradeoff here is that you will need to reschedule this alarm each time it goes off.